# Objects stop emitting smoke/fire after a short time?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

How can I maintain the flames on the pieces of an object after an explosion?

Here's a [video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2t13YdC3iw&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Looks like you need to extend the smoke sim cache length, in *physics > smoke cache > end* with the domain selected.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Tried to increase it to the end but it did not change anything. Got any more suggestions? thanks..

Comment: @geric you would have to increase it, then bake those new frames.

Comment: @BlendingJake. By increasing it you mean the flame rate right? I'm going to watch some videos on baking now. I am still new to blender. Any advice on how to bake while I watch more tutorials on it? Thanks again!

Comment: @geric Sorry, no. I meant the cache length. You should just be able to extend it out past 250 frames. Then try "Bake From Cache" which might just bake the new frames. Else click "Bake". I think what is happening is you tried extending the cache length like gandalf3 said, but then didn't bake to put all that in the cache, but I might be wrong.

Comment: are your pieces be the emitting objects?

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the smoke cache length in *Properties > 
Physics > Smoke cache* with the domain object selected:

[image]

Note that you will have to free any existing bakes before you can edit that value.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.8 the icons and arrangement of the options has changed. You first need to select the smoke domain. then in the properties go to the physics tab. then find the cache and change the end:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in this case I think updating gandalf's post (by [suggesting an edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/18000/edit)) seems more appropriate...? What do you think?

Comment: I thought of that but many people like to use the pre 2.8 GUI and that answer will be valuable,  at least for a while.

Comment: Huh, but the only difference is that it looks a bit different, the actual path to the property is the same so I don't get why this have to be a separate answer (I mean we can have two screens in 1 answer).